# Google sheets newbie - corresponding cells autofill based on dropdown choice

Tags: function, range, dropdown

I am trying to create an inventory system. I have all the items in a spreadsheet and have them grouped according to Named Ranges. In another spreadsheet, I have dropdown menus for separate areas (ex. cardstock, embellishments,vinyl, etc) where only the actual name of the item is listed ( column C entries). I want to be able to enter a quanity and have the money value (column G in the original spreadsheet) of the dropdown selection produce the product answer.   If I choose "gray glossy" from the dropdown, the value is $2 and I want to multiply that by, let's say, a quanitity of 6 to give me $12 in the cell chosen. Is this possible or am I just wishing?

I have tried setting up additional Named Ranges that include the smaller group. (ex. Vinyl is set up for 4-57, and Vinyl_names are set up for C4-C57) When I try using the named range in my Lookup function I get an error messaged.